# How do i search an array in php and return true if it finds one of my variable?

Tags: php, arrays, search, boolean, return

```
if (array_search($soca, $user_socs))
```

I know that this will search the array by inputing a variable and an array but i was wondering if it is possible to make it return true, because since it doesn't return true, my if statement is not being carried out.

#### References

- [`array_search` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: give some example what u tried and what u need ?

Comment: A little more detail woudl be nice. An example of the array you are working with and the value you are looking for would be useful.

Comment: Just use the boolean `!== false` in your condition. `if` block is `true`, else is not found. note that index zero is valid so don't compare loosely. this is already covered in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php (see warning)

Comment: so say i want to find a specific society that the user is in, so i could decide whether to show a join link or a leave link, so if the result returns true, then it means the user is in that society and a leave link is needed, else vice versa, so $soca is the society variable, and $user_socs is the list of societies that the user is part of. thank you

Comment: But does the array_search function return true, because i heard it returns "Returns the key of a value if it is found in the array" and not true, which causes my if statement not to be carried out.

Comment: @FangXIII its very simple, if it returns `false (bool)`, then its not found, it returns the key if found. there is no `true (bool)` returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to code this function to expect a return of `FALSE` if it does not find what you are looking for.

So

```
if (array_search($soca, $user_socs) !== false) {
    // then I found something
    // not sure what but its defintely not 
    // returning a failed to find situation
} else {
    // I did not find anything
}
```

Note the use of the `!==` and NOT `!=` this is expressly for situations where a function can return actual data that might equate to false but not actually be false i.e. where it may return the 0'th occurance its a valid occurance which may be confused with false if you just us `==`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($key = array_search($soca, $user_socs)) !== FALSE) {
  ...
}
```